# How would I get my app to display a error message instead of the broken image link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getDogImage(breed) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => 
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  //replace the existing image with the new one
    $('.results-img').replaceWith(
      `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
     ).on("error", function() { alert("the image could not load"); }
  )
  
  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage($('#breed').val());
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Dog API Example</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>
           
        <form>
             <label for="breed">Breed</label>
      <input type="search" name="phone" id="breed" placeholder="Enter Breed" title="dog breeds" required/>

          <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
        </form>
        <section class="results hidden">
          <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
          <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
        </section>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How would  I get my app to display a error message instead of the broken image link upon submitting a non-valid breed name. There should be an alert or error message shown if the API is unable to locate the breed name passed in. At the moment, a broken image link is displayed when passing in a non-valid breed name. Im a beginner just looking for help from experienced developers.

Comment: You need to add code to `displayResults` to check `responseJson` to see if the `status` property is "error". If so, show your error message.

Answer (score 0):

In your first then callback, you pass a success handler that parses the json.
You continue on that promise chain and add catch afterwards.
However the faulty data is already passed into your display results function.
So instead you could validate the reponse from fetch first.

```
function getDogImage(breed) {
fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
.then(response => {
   if (response.status !== 200) {
     //some error handling code
     alert('invalid response code');
     throw Error();
   }
   return response.json()
})
.then(responseJson => 
  displayResults(responseJson))
.catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}
```

The following will launch both alerts on an invalid breed but not the displayResults function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an if statement to check if there was an error:

```js
function getDogImage(breed) {
  fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${breed}/images/random`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson =>
      displayResults(responseJson))
    .catch(error => alert('Something went wrong. Try again later.'));
}

function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  // Added an if statement here to check if there was an error
  if (responseJson.status === "error") {
    alert("could not find that dog breed!");
    return;
  }
  //replace the existing image with the new one
  $('.results-img').replaceWith(
    `<img src="${responseJson.message}" class="results-img">`
  ).on("error", function() {
    alert("the image could not load");
  })

  //display the results section
  $('.results').removeClass('hidden');
}

function watchForm() {
  $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getDogImage($('#breed').val());
  });
}

$(function() {
  console.log('App loaded! Waiting for submit!');
  watchForm();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Dog API Example</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Dog API: A Simple Example</h1>

    <form>
      <label for="breed">Breed</label>
      <input type="search" name="phone" id="breed" placeholder="Enter Breed" title="dog breeds" required/>

      <input type="submit" value="Get a dog pic!">
    </form>
    <section class="results hidden">
      <h2>Look at this dog!</h2>
      <img class="results-img" alt="placeholder">
    </section>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I added an if statement at the beginning of the `displayResults` function:

```js
function displayResults(responseJson) {
  console.log(responseJson);
  // Added an if statement here to check if there was an error
  if (responseJson.status === "error") {
    alert("could not find that dog breed!");
    return;
  }
  // rest of the function
```

Hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use this all the time, just pop it into a `<script></script>` section on your page:

**Show default image on image error:**

```
//Detect 404 errors on page
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {            
    //Fix any broken images found
     e.target.src = "/images/placeholder.jpg";
    }, true);
```

Nice & easy!

PS. Alternatively, if you don't want to set a default image, just overwrite the entire element using this code! Once again, place inside a `<script></script>` tag on your page.

**Show error message on image error & hide image + image alt text:**

```
//Detect 404 errors on page
window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {            
    //Create new error message
     e.target.parentNode.innerHTML = "Custom Error Message";
    }, true);
```